# Oracle: Get All Rows Except One

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am stuck with a simple query. What i want is to get all rows except one Kindly have a look at the following data.

```
COL_A   COL_B
B       D
B       (null)
B       C
G       D
G       (null)
G       C
```

I want to get all rows except but **B C**. Kindly have a look at the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33a62/6)

I have tried to get the rows by anding `col_A <> 'B' and col_B <> 'C'` but it's not anding the operation. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the SQL to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
where not(col_A = 'B' and col_B = 'C')
```

or

```
where col_A <> 'B' or col_B <> 'C'
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution. Maybe not the most elegant:

```
select req_for col_A, doc_typ col_B 
from a
where (req_for IS NULL OR doc_typ IS NULL) 
OR (req_for,doc_typ) 
NOT IN (select 'B','C' from dual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `NULL` values.  Here is a concise way of expressing this in Oracle:

```
where (col_A || col_B) <>  'BC'
```

Oracle treats `NULL` values as the empty string in string concatenation.

Comment: What if both columns are null?

Comment: @user2672165 . . . Then the result will be `''`/NULL and the condition will fail.  However, the sample data has no `NULL` values in the first column.  Because there are NULLs in the second, I can reasonably assume that this is not an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, negatives. Always causing trouble. With a SQL query like this you have to think about what you want to INCLUDE, not what you want to EXCLUDE.

If you do `where nvl(doc_typ,'NA') <> 'C' and nvl(req_for, 'NA') <> 'B';`, you aren't including any rows with doc_type of C, and you aren't including any rows with req_for of B.

You want to do `where nvl(doc_typ,'NA') <> 'C' or nvl(req_for, 'NA') <> 'B';`. This way a doc_type of C will still be included, as long as its req_for isn't also B.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just remove the unwanted row:

```
select req_for col_A, doc_typ col_B from a
where NOT (NVL(doc_typ,'NA') = 'C' AND nvl(req_for,'NA') = 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select req_for col_A, doc_typ col_B from a
where req_for||doc_typ != 'BC';

select req_for col_A, doc_typ col_B from a
where case when req_for = 'B' and doc_typ='C' then 0 else 1 end > 0
```